# Comma Separated String of ids map to values in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a comma separated string in a columns in pandas DataFrame:

[image: Table 1]

I have a mapping Dataframe

[image: mapping table]

I want the final Dataframe:

[image: Values]

I want a new column and replace the ids with values from the mapping dataframe, what is the write pythonic + pandas way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.split`, `replace` and join back into str:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Index":[0,1], "ids":["1,2,3", "1,2,3"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3], "value":["value1", "value2", "value3"]})

df["value"] = (df["ids"].str.split(",", expand=True).astype(int)
                        .replace(df2.set_index("id")["value"])
                        .agg(lambda d: ",".join(i for i in d if isinstance(i, str)), axis=1))

print (df)

   Index    ids                 value
0      0  1,2,3  value1,value2,value3
1      1  1,2,3  value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: hmm some ids dont have value in the mapping, is there anyway i can handle the error?

Comment: well what do you want to do with them then?

Comment: ignore/skip them, id 135 is missing, so if 1,2,3,4,135,5 -> skip 135 and the final value will be value1,value2,value3,value4,value5.